# Python Mercurial how to get diff with hg library

Tags: python, mercurial

I use Python to code a tool to get status and diff of a Mercurial repository. It's easy to get status but when I try to get diff I get this error : **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'configbool'**.
This is my code and the output:

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding:utf-8

import os
import sys

from mercurial import ui, hg, commands
from mercurial.i18n import gettext as _

path = '~/path_of/repo'

u = ui.ui()
repo = hg.repository(u, path)

status = repo.status()
print("===== status =====")
print(status)

diff = commands.diff(ui, repo)
print("===== diff =====")
print(diff)
```

### Ouput

```
===== status =====
(['app/file/file_modified.py'], [], [], [], [], [], [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    diff = commands.diff(ui, repo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 2940, in diff
    diffopts = patch.diffopts(ui, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/patch.py", line 1557, in diffopts
    def get(key, name=None, getter=ui.configbool):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'configbool'
zsh: exit 1     python test.py
```

Do you have a way to get the diff of a repo with Python ?

Comment: You shouldn't use mercurial as a library since it doesn't have a stable API. You probably want to use python-hglib instead: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PythonHglib

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm able to get the plain text diff.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to ngoldbaum's comments, I installed **python-hglib**:

```
apt-get install python-hglib
```

Then, I code this function to get diff lines in object:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding:utf-8

import re

import hglib


def get_diff(path, include_empty_lines=False):
    client = hglib.open(path) # get client of repo
    diff = client.diff() # get plain text diff
    added_lines = []
    removed_lines = []
    current_file = ''
    for line in diff.split("\n")[1:]:
        if line.startswith('+++'):
            current_file = re.split('\s',line)[1][2:]
            continue
        if not line.startswith('+++') and not line.startswith('---'):
            if line.startswith('+'):
                if include_empty_lines or line[1:]:
                    added_lines.append({
                        "file": current_file,
                        "line_content": line[1:]
                        })
            if line.startswith('-'):
                if include_empty_lines or line[1:]:
                    removed_lines.append({
                        "file": current_file,
                        "line_content": line[1:]
                        })
    return {"added_lines":added_lines, "removed_lines":removed_lines}


diff = get_diff('/path/to/repo')
print(diff)

# gives
# {
#   'added_lines': 
#       [
#           {
#               'line_content': 'import re', 
#               'file': 'bestfile.py'
#           }, 
#           {
#               'line_content': '        re.split("\s", name)', 
#               'file': 'parsing_file.py'
#           }
#       ], 
#   'removed_lines': 
#       [
#           {
#               'line_content': '        name.split(" ")',
#               'file': 'parsing_file.py'
#           }
#       ]
#  }
```

I hope this code will helps !